# build R package using report generation with knitr

Tags: r, package, knitr

I am doing report generation in R with knitr.
So basically I have a dataset, do some preprocessing and then call knitr to output an html report.
This means the entire workflow consists of several R code files and some .Rhtml templates which are needed later on for report generation.

I would like to wrap all of this into a R package.
Having just .r files I would just run package.skeleton() and have a start..

But, how do I deal with the .Rhtml files. What is the proper way to deal with these when building a R package?

Thanks,

Comment: put them in a directory within an `inst` directory and use `system.file()` to retrieve them?

Comment: Thanks, this will definitely work with the .Rhtml files. 
Thats probably already the solution...

Comment: if it works, you can post it as an answer if you like.

Comment: I just uploaded a package to CRAN today called `reports` that sounds like this project may be a good candidate for but I'm not sure.  The package allows you to create templates and load them in a manner similar to what you describe.

Comment: Just an additional note: since R 3.0.0 (to be released in April), you can have `*.Rhtml` files under `inst/doc/` and they will be recognized as package vignettes just like `*.Rnw` files; see http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/ for instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben Bolkers answer: 
put them in a directory within an inst directory and use system.file() to retrieve them.